# Rock paper scissors in java using modulus

Tags: java

I'm getting stuck at the modulus calculation as well as the condition for this game. Any suggestions?

```
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int x, comp, result;
      x = 0;
      String user; 
      String computer_choice = null; //declare variables for each value
     // generate computer number 
      comp =  (int) (3 * Math.random()) + 1 ;
      System.out.println (comp);
      //convert# to a value
      if (comp == 0 )
      {
          computer_choice = "Rock";
      }

      else if (comp == 1 )
      {
          computer_choice = "Paper";
      }

      else if (comp == 2 )
      {
          computer_choice = "Scissor";
      }
      // print out the message
      System.out.println ("Please select one of [R/P/S]: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      user = keyboard.nextLine(); 

      if (user.equals ("R")|| user.equals("r"))
         {
            user = "Rock";
            x = 0; // rock
         }
      else if (user.equals ("P")|| user.equals("p"))
      {
          user = "Paper";
          x = 1;//paper
      }
      else if (user.equals ("S")|| user.equals("s"))
      {
          user = "Scissor";
          x = 2;
      }
      else
      { System.out.println ("Please enter a valid values");
      }
    System.out.println ("You chose: " + user);
    //print out the computer choice  

     System.out.println ("I chose\t" + computer_choice);

     result = (comp - x ) % 3 ;

    System.out.println (result);
     if (result == 0 )// if the game is tie
     {
         System.out.println ("A Tie!") ;
     }

     else if (result == 1 || result == 2 )
     {

         System.out.println ("comp win");
     }

     else
     {
         System.out.println ("you win");

     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Properly indent your code.

Comment: Why are you using mod? Why not using if else ?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition would always result in either a Tie or the computer winning.

Based on the rules :

0 beats 2
 
1 beats 0
 
2 beats 1
 
otherwise - Tie

We can write down a table of all possible combinations :

```
computer |player |computer - player | mod 3 | winner
-----------------------------------------------------
0        | 0     |     0            |  0    |  tie
0        | 1     |     -1           |  2    |  player
0        | 2     |     -2           |  1    |  comp
1        | 0     |     1            |  1    |  comp
1        | 1     |     0            |  0    |  tie
1        | 2     |     -1           |  2    |  player
2        | 0     |     2            |  2    |  player
2        | 1     |     1            |  1    |  comp
2        | 2     |     0            |  0    |  tie
```

In all the cases where the computer wins, the difference `comp - x` is -2 or 1, and both are 1 modulu 3.

In all the cases where the player wins, the difference `comp - x` is -1 or 2, and both are 2 modulu 3.

Therefore the correct logic would be :

```
 if (result == 0 ) {
     System.out.println ("A Tie!") ;
 } else if (result == 1) {
     System.out.println ("comp win");
 } else {
     System.out.println ("you win");
 }
```

As Henry corrected, Java's modulu behaves differently for negative numbers, so you should change the calculation of result to :

```
result = (comp + 3 - x ) % 3 ;
```

Comment: Since -2 % 3 == -2 in Java better write the test `result = (comp - x + 3 ) % 3 ;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I was doing this based on logic that I did for python rock, paper, scissor, lizard, spock games. the formal was  (user-computer)%5 and i got a correct result. Why is there a a difference in java. Would you be able to explain.

THANKS again.